# How to implement a method that calls any constructor like emplace_back in vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

So I want to implement a method like C++11's emplace_back in std vector for a memorypool class that I'm implementing. The idea is that I have a typename T of my memorypool and when the user calls emplace_back, he passes and calls the constructor of T on a memory region I got. I'm not sure how this can be done as it seems to use some inner features of c++ which I'm not aware of. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Look up placement new.

Comment: Probably relevant https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/perfect-forwarding.html

Comment: Don't take it as a personal slight that this question has been closed as a duplicate.  Finding the right words to search for is hard if you don't know the answer.  SO leaves duplicates up as a signpost for other people to the canonical question and its answer.